# How to render static html file in MVC Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using static files middleware to access customer specific resources located outside wwwroot. These resources include CSS and image files, and are accessible at ~/resources. For example, customer-specific css is located here :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/resources/css/customer.css" />
```

Now I would like to serve a static html file located in ~/resources/html/static.html. I created a model which contains only a HtmlString property, and I wish to inject the content of static.html inside a standard cshtml using this model. Here is my controller action :

```
public IActionResult MentionsLegales()
{
    var filePath = IO.Path.Combine(
        _env.ContentRootPath, "PersonnalisationClient", _config["PersonnalisationClient:NomClient"], "html", "mentionslegales.html");

    var mentionsLegalesModel = new MentionsLegalesModel();

    if (IO.File.Exists(filePath))
        mentionsLegalesModel.Content = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString(IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath));
    else
    {
        _logger.LogWarning($"Le fichier {filePath} est introuvable");
        mentionsLegalesModel.Content = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString(string.Empty);
    }
    return View(mentionsLegalesModel);
}
```

As you can see, here I access the file through its physical path. It's working but I'm not satisfied with this solution. I wanted to read the file through its server path, which is ~/resources/html/mentionslegales.html, but I don't know how to do that. Apparently in non-Core MVC one could use Server.MapPath for such purpose, but I couldn't find an equivalent in MVC core. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: `Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "resources/html/mentionslegales.html")` allows you to use the server path (as a relative path though)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that's already what I tried to do. _env.ContentRootPath gives me the absolute physical path : C:\\Users\\xxx\\.... What I want is to read the file from its relative server URI : ~/resources/html/mentionslegales.html.

Comment: _"that's already what I tried to do"_ - well, `IO.Path.Combine(
        _env.ContentRootPath, "PersonnalisationClient", _config["PersonnalisationClient:NomClient"], "html", "mentionslegales.html");` looks to me like you're building the path manually, rather that letting `Path.Combine` combine it for you. There is no equivalent of `Server.MapPath` in ASP net core, so using `IHostingEnvironment` is your only option.

Comment: I don't think I misuse Path.Combine as you suggest, it's buiding a correct physical path. I was just looking for another way to do that, because I'm afraid the physical path would change depending on where the app is published. I wish I was able to easily load my static html from the controller, using a relative URI.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't suggesting it was misusing it, just that if you wanted to use the 'server path' you could combine that with the content root.

Comment: No problem ;) I think I didn't make myself clear enough. What I meant by "server path" or "relative URI" is a http virtual path, not a path on a physical drive. Ideally I would serve my static html file like a cshtml view : ```return View("~/resources/html/mentionslegales.html");```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call the static resources in the [folder outside the web root directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#serve-files-outside-of-web-root) in the page, you could configure the Static File Middleware in `Configure` method as follows:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "resources")),
    RequestPath = "/resources"
});
```

Then reference the file like below:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/resources/css/customer.css" />
```

`return View()` is reserved for returning the result of a view execution, i.e. a **Razor CSHTML** page. You can't use an HTML page for that.Try to redirect directly:

```
return Redirect("~/resources/html/mentionslegales.html");
```

Refer to the links below which may be help you better understand how to return static html pages from the controller.

[How to make a get request for an HTML file using ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49524917/how-to-make-a-get-request-for-an-html-file-using-asp-net-core-mvc)

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3751

**Update:**

For injecting the static html in the View , you could refer to :

Controller

```
 public IActionResult GetStaticFile()
 {
        var mentionsLegalesModel = new MentionsLegalesModel();
        var htmlString = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("./resources/html/mentionslegales.html");
        mentionsLegalesModel.Content = string.Join("", htmlString);
        return View(mentionsLegalesModel);
  }
```

View:

```
@model MentionsLegalesModel

@Html.Raw(Model.Content)
```

Also you could try the Partial view suggested on the above first link

Comment: Thank you, I had figured out the static files middleware part but I missed the Redirect method. However, I don't know how I could inject the static html in my View using this. I've looked into VirtualFileResult class but I don't quite understand how it works.

Comment: @BlackMushroom , check my updated . The VirtualFileResult class needs the virtual path to the file which is in the wwwroot , you could refer to https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-core-demystified-action-results/

Comment: As I feared, the method GetStaticFile() is not working because System.IO.File.ReadAllLines expects a "real" physical file path, not the virtual path defined by static files middleware. The only way I can think of is to use a HttpClient to download the file, but that seems odd because the file is on the same server. Thanks for the link anyway, that's a good one :)